# CAKeyframeAnimation with staggered begin time

Tags: ios, core-animation

I'm trying to create an animation where items come in to view staggered in time. To this end I used a CAKeyframeAnimation but to achieve the staggering I need to specify a `beginTime`.

The problem is that I'd also like the animation not to snap back to the original position when it completes so I specify the value on the model as follows: `view.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity` *before* the animation is added to the layer.

The animation does, however, snap back to the initial position because I've specified a beginTime. Is there a way around this?

```swift
func addAnimation(view: UIView, index: Int) {
    let values = RK4SpringAnimation(tension: 600, friction: 60, initialVelocity: 0) // just provides an array of values between 0.0 and 1.0.
    let positions = values.map { Float(view.layer.frame.width) - (Float($0) * Float(view.layer.frame.width)) }
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    animation.values = positions
    animation.duration = 0.716
    animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + Double(index) * 0.015
    view.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity // set the final value on the model.
    view.layer.add(animation, forKey: "transform2")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you add the animation, you should set the property value to the final value of the animation. Is the final value `CATransform3DIdentity`?

If the animation's `beginTime` is in the future, and the animation's begin value is not equal to its end value, then you can set `animation.fillMode = .backwards` to tell Core Animation to apply the animation's begin value to the layer until `beginTime` is reached.

```
func addAnimation(view: UIView, index: Int, show: Bool) {
    let values = RK4SpringAnimation(tension: 600, friction: 60, initialVelocity: 0) // just provides an array of values between 0.0 and 1.0.
    let positions = values.map { Float(view.layer.frame.width) - (Float($0) * Float(view.layer.frame.width)) }
    let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.x")
    animation.values = positions
    animation.duration = 0.716
    animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + Double(index) * 0.015
    animation.fillMode = .backwards
    view.layer.add(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
    view.layer.setValue(positions.last!, forKey: animation.keyPath!)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way I used to solve this problem is to set a `CAAnimationDelegate` for your animations and implement `animationDidStop(CAAnimation, finished: Bool)`. Create a reference to your view's layer and set the desired transformation when the animation has finished.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the view is the layer's delegate so unless I add another layer this won't work right?. The views, in this case, are UILabels...

Comment: Each `CAAnimation` object can have its own delegate, independent of the layer's delegate.

Comment: You set the delegate for ´CAAnimation´ and not for the layer it is applied to. ´CAAnimationDelegate´ will receive callbacks for begin and end of the animation. The actual problem with this approach is, that ´CAAnimation´ has no reference to the layer, it was applied to...